# Difference between include and chaining classes using arrows in Puppet

Tags: puppet

What is the difference between

```
class A {

}

class B {
  Class['B'] -> Class['A']
}
```

and

```
class A {

}

class B {
  require a
}
```

To my understanding they should be the same - establishing that 'A' is executed before 'B', but only the second form seems to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> -> (ordering arrow; a hyphen and a greater-than sign) — Applies the resource on the left before the resource on the right.

So in your first example:

```
Class['B'] -> Class['A']
```

means apply `B` before `A`.

In second example, the [require function](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_classes.html#using-require) causes `A` to become a dependency of `B`. Simplifying apply `A` before `B`.

Comment: Ah, even though I read the docs I failed to parse that i applied the ordering arrow incorrectly. Thanks!